# Create variables from loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I want to be able to create variables with a loop going up to 299. For example, I have the variable $var1 and want to be able to add from there example: $var2 - $var3 - $var4 etc.

```
for ( $x = 1; $x<=299; $x++ ) 
    {
    $var1 = substr($size, 0, 1); 
    if ($var1 == '1') { $c1 = 'COLOR1'; } 
          elseif ($var1 == '2') { $var1 = 'COLOR2'; } 
          elseif ($var1 == '3') { $var1 = 'COLOR3'; };
    }
```

This has been bugging me for sometime.

Comment: (1) Which language? PHP? (2) No, that's probably not what you want to do, you almost certainly want to use a hash/dictionary/associative-array/... instead.

Comment: "Variable Variables": http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php.  But because this might be risky and very inefficient, I can't say this is an answer.  Instead, it looks like the best solution in your case is to use arrays like mu is too short suggested.

Comment: @Bryan How will you use this? Perhaps we could offer a better solution.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson, perhaps. I'm trying align a Div ID with that Variable so that I can change the substr of that variable for that div.

Comment: And what did you figure out?  A question with no answer is a waste of electrons, and nobody else will provide an answer now that you're unlikely to tag anything as the correct one.

Comment: If I knew how to operate this great website like you did, then yes, I'd be more helpful. I appreciate you're waste of electrons with your useless comment, and a long with mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

use arrays in a better way:

```
for ( $x = 1; $x<=299; $x++ ) {
    $var[$x] = substr($size, 0, 1); 
    switch($var[$x]) {
       case "1":  $var[$x] = 'COLOR1'; break;
       case "2":  $var[$x] = 'COLOR2'; break;
       case "3":  $var[$x] = 'COLOR3'; break;
    }

    // or the more simple if you follow the same rule
    // $var[$x] = "COLOR".$var[$x];
}
```